# ifstream in C++ not accepting a variable

Tags: c++, string, fstream, getline

I have tried to use the following snippet of code:

```
int main()
{
string location_file ("test.txt");
string data;

ifstream file (location_file);
getline (file, data);
file.close();

cout << data;
return 0;
}
```

But it won't work. Now, if I were to use "ifstream file ("test.txt")" it would. Why? Isn't it the same thing in the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `ifstream`'s constructor does not accept a `string` as parameter, but only a `char const*`. Now `"test.txt"` is of type `char const[9]` which decays into `char const*` according to type promotion rules, therefore it works. However, there's no implicit conversion from `string` to `char const*`, therefore your code doesn't work.

To fix your code, construct your stream with:

```
ifstream file(location_file.c_str());
```

Comment: @pmr: About your edit: A declaration that includes an initializer *is* a definition (well, with a few exceptions, but this isn't one of them).

Comment: @celtschk Alright. Does that mean definition is used differently when referring to function/class definitions and when used for names?

Comment: @pmr: You don't define names. YOu can define types (including classes), functions, templates, or (as in this case) objects. A declaration makes the name of the entity known. A definition (which always also is a declaration) also provides the entity itself. For example, the following (at global/namespace scope) declares, but does not define an object of type int: `extern int a;` The following defines it (without initializer): `int a;` And the following also defines that object (of course not both may be present): `extern int a = 3`. Note: The rules which decls are also defs depend on the scope.

Answer (score 5):

Because in earlier versions of the C++ standard, there was (irritatingly) no constructor for `ifstream` that took a `string`, so you'd have to do:

```
ifstream file(location_file.c_str());
```

Comment: Not inexplicably: The idea was that the different parts were mostly independent from each other, so you could use `fstream`s without at the same time using `string`s. A constructor taking `string` would have coupled `fstream` and `string`. It may not have been a good decision (I don't think it was), but it definitely wasn't inexplicable.

Comment: An alternate explanation is that streams were designed long before there even was a std::string, so there wasn't a decision to make.

Comment: @BoPersson: While that is true, they were *standardized* at the same time (namely for the first standardized version), and the components were definitely revised to work well together (e.g. `string` was "STLized" by adding member functions like `begin`, `end` and `size` (the latter being redundant with `length`). Adding a constructor taking `string` would have been a backwards-compatible change, and I remember the problem of passing `string` to the `fstream` constructor being discussed several times on Usenet around that time, in groups frequented by C++ standard committee members.